# Why is the wrong object removed?

Tags: javascript, class, dom, object, reference

I've written this simple class to create a div element with a message which should disappear after the given time. This works great, but when creating multiple messages with this the hide and destroy functions will only apply on the last created message.

This is my class:

```
function message(text, duration){
    var self = this;

    function init(){
        this.obj = document.createElement("div");
        this.obj.setAttribute("class", "message");
        this.obj.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
        document.body.appendChild(this.obj);
        setTimeout(function(){self.display.call(this);}, 20);
        setTimeout(function(){self.hide.call(this);}, duration);
        setTimeout(function(){self.destroy.call(this);}, duration+1000);
    }

    this.display = function(){
        this.obj.setAttribute("class", "message display");
    }

    this.hide = function(){
        this.obj.setAttribute("class", "message gone");
    }

    this.destroy = function(){
        document.body.removeChild(this.obj);
    }

    init();
}
```

This works:

```
new message("This will be removed in 5 seconds.", 5000);
```

This doesn't work as it should be:

```
new message("This will not be shown", 2000);
new message("This will be removed after 2 seconds", 5000);
```

There might be some reference error but i can't spot any.

Comment: It would be useful to include a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/dGpXJ/) of your code.

Comment: `this` inside `setTimeout` is probably not what you think it is...

Comment: You have `var self = this` to avoid problems of nested functions not having the right `this` (which is good), but then you don't use `self` *nearly* as often as you need to. That is: you have tons of uses of `this` that are actually referring to `window`. As a result, all of your functions operate on `window.obj` instead of on instance-specific `obj` fields.

Comment: Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dkf89/

Comment: Further on `self`, you can say `self.display();`, you don't need to use `.call()` to do `self.display.call(this);` (even if `this` was what you expected at that point, which it isn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close to a working solution. I've fixed the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/GTpKV/

You (correctly) make `self` reference to this, but inside your code you still use `this` (`this` is lost when using inner functions, and you also call init directly, which means `this` will refer to `window` in that case. Had you used `this.init()` it would have created the references correctly on the object, but then the timeouts would have messed things up). The safest way (which I've taken), is to simply replace all occurrences of `this` with `self`. Another idea would be to analyze when the context is correct, and when it is not. But since you already have a correctly bound context in `self`, you might as well use it. Here is the corrected code found in the JSFiddle link as well:

```
function message(text, duration){
    var self = this;

    function init(){
        self.obj = document.createElement("div");
        self.obj.setAttribute("class", "message");
        self.obj.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
        document.body.appendChild(self.obj);
        setTimeout(function(){self.display();}, 20);
        setTimeout(function(){self.hide();}, duration);
        setTimeout(function(){self.destroy();}, duration+1000);
    }

    this.display = function(){
        self.obj.setAttribute("class", "message display");
    }

    this.hide = function(){
        self.obj.setAttribute("class", "message gone");
    }

    this.destroy = function(){
        document.body.removeChild(self.obj);
    }

    init();
}

new message("This will not be shown", 2000);
new message("This will be removed in 5 seconds.", 5000);
```

Comment: Instead of: `self.display.call(self);` Just do: `self.display();`. Don't really need `.call()` there.

Comment: Very true. Fixed (on mobile... So hopefully fixed)

Answer (score 1):

I believe these `this`'es becomes `window`:

```
setTimeout(function(){self.display.call(this);}, 20);
setTimeout(function(){self.hide.call(this);}, duration);
setTimeout(function(){self.destroy.call(this);}, duration+1000);
```

So try with:

```
setTimeout(function(){self.display()}, 20);
setTimeout(function(){self.hide()}, duration);
setTimeout(function(){self.destroy()}, duration+1000);
```

Also, why not use `self` for the rest of the code:

```
function init(){
    self.obj = document.createElement("div");
    self.obj.setAttribute("class", "message");
    self.obj.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    document.body.appendChild(self.obj);
    setTimeout(function(){self.display()}, 20);
    setTimeout(function(){self.hide()}, duration);
    setTimeout(function(){self.destroy()}, duration+1000);
}

this.display = function(){
    self.obj.setAttribute("class", "message display");
}

this.hide = function(){
    self.obj.setAttribute("class", "message gone");
}

this.destroy = function(){
    document.body.removeChild(self.obj);
}
```

(I think I got them all.. let me know if I too missed a spot)

Comment: This is a good start, but then those methods need to be changed to operate on `self` instead of their `this`.

Comment: In your second code block, these: `setTimeout(self.display, 20);` are going to have the same `this` issue.

Comment: Regarding your update, that'll almost work, but you forgot to add the `()` to invoke the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try this as a solution. Get rid if the `init` function and change the `this` inside you `setTimeout`s to `self`, and do away with the unnecessary `call`.

Javascript

```
function message(text, duration) {
    var self = this;

    this.display = function () {
        this.obj.setAttribute("class", "message display");
    }

    this.hide = function () {
        this.obj.setAttribute("class", "message gone");
    }

    this.destroy = function () {
        document.body.removeChild(this.obj);
    }

    this.obj = document.createElement("div");
    this.obj.setAttribute("class", "message");
    this.obj.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    document.body.appendChild(this.obj);
    setTimeout(function () {
        self.display(self);
    }, 20);
    setTimeout(function () {
        self.hide(self);
    }, duration);
    setTimeout(function () {
        self.destroy(self);
    }, duration + 1000);
}

new message("This will not be shown", 2000);
new message("This will be removed after 2 seconds", 5000);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/dGpXJ/1/)